# JPA Hibernate - @ManyToOne not getting correctly

Tags: java, hibernate, ejb, fetch, many-to-one

I'm using JPA (Hibernate) and I have a problem when I try to fetch an object from my database. I'm using Glassfish 3.1.2, Hibernate and Oracle database 10.2.0.4.

Here is the concept of my application:

A answer is an answer to a form. A form belong to a category. A user can create forms. A user can answer.

So:

- 1 form has one category, so 1 category may have several forms
- 1 answer has 1 form, 1 form may have several answers
- 1 answer has 1 user (the answer author)
- 1 form has 1 user (the form creator)

If I try to get the answers I get an error (see bottom of the post) but what's strange is the fact that:

- If no answer in database; it works (at least no error thrown)
- If answers exist in database without any value in the answer.form_id column; it works (at least no error thrown)
- If I remove the form attribute and let user attribute from the answer class; it works! Answers are get from database and has a user fetched too.
- If I remove the user attribute and let form attribute from the answer class; it fails! Answers are not get from database. (throwing the error at the end of this post)
- If I remove the category and user attributes from the **form** class; it works! Answers are get from database and has a user and a form fetched too! But I can't let it like this, I need to have a category and a user in the form entity.
- If I remove either category attribute or either user attribute and let the other one in the form class; it fails.

It seems that hibernate cannot fetch further than one other entity:

- Answer > user : OK
- Answer > form without category or user: OK
- form > category: OK
- form > user: OK
- Answer > form > category: FAIL
- Answer > form > user: FAIL

However I set `<property name="hibernate.max_fetch_depth" value="3"/>` in my persistence.xml.

Any ideas or suggestions of what's the problem? It seems to be either the form entity either its attributes category or user.

Thanks

---

Here is my actual code, heavily reduced for clarity.

Form class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="FORM")
public class Form implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -2101681231828548611L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "G_FORM")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "G_FORM", sequenceName = "FORM_ID_SEQ")
    @Column(name = "ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private int id;

    private String name;

    @ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.EAGER) @JoinColumn
    private Category category;

    @ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.EAGER) @JoinColumn
    private User user;

    //more fields and usual getters and setters
}
```

User class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "USERS")
public class User implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -821421797110076396L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private String id;

    @NotNull
    @Column
    private String email;

    @NotNull
    private String password;

    @Column(name="PARENT_ID")
    private User parent;

    //more fields and usual getters and setters
}
```

Answer class:

```
@Entity
public class Answer implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -8514559401482729639L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "G_ANSWER")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "G_ANSWER", sequenceName = "ANSWER_ID_SEQ")
    @Column(name = "ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private int id;

    @ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.EAGER) @JoinColumn
    private Form form;

    @ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.EAGER) @JoinColumn
    private User user;

    //more fields and usual getters and setters
}
```

AnswerDAO method that fail:

```
public List<Answer> getAllAnswers() throws Exception{
    TypedQuery<Answer> query = em.createQuery( "SELECT a FROM Answer a ORDER BY a.id", Answer.class );
    return query.getResultList();
    //return em.createQuery("SELECT a FROM Answer a", Answer.class).getResultList();
}
```

In my persistence.xml:

```
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
<property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect"/>
<property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
<property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/>
<property name="hibernate.max_fetch_depth" value="3"/>
```

The sql generated by hibernate (seems correct?):

```
Infos: Hibernate: select answer0_.ID as ID1_0_, answer0_.ANSWER_XML as ANSWER2_0_, answer0_.DATE_UPLOAD as DATE3_0_, answer0_.form_ID as form4_0_, answer0_.user_ID as user5_0_ from Answer answer0_ order by answer0_.ID
Infos: Hibernate: select form0_.ID as ID1_2_2_, form0_.category_NAME as category6_2_2_, form0_.DATE_UPLOAD as DATE2_2_2_, form0_.extention as extentio3_2_2_, form0_.name as name4_2_2_, form0_.QUESTION_XML as QUESTION5_2_2_, form0_.user_ID as user7_2_2_, category1_.NAME as NAME1_1_0_, category1_.DATE_CREATION as DATE2_1_0_, user2_.ID as ID1_5_1_, user2_.ANSWER_COUNT as ANSWER2_5_1_, user2_.DATE_INSCRIPTION as DATE3_5_1_, user2_.DATE_LAST_ANSWER as DATE4_5_1_, user2_.DATE_LAST_LOGIN as DATE5_5_1_, user2_.email as email6_5_1_, user2_.firstname as firstnam7_5_1_, user2_.FORM_COUNT as FORM8_5_1_, user2_.lastname as lastname9_5_1_, user2_.PARENT_ID as PARENT10_5_1_, user2_.password as passwor11_5_1_ from FORM form0_ left outer join Category category1_ on form0_.category_NAME=category1_.NAME left outer join USERS user2_ on form0_.user_ID=user2_.ID where form0_.ID=?
```

The error in the eclipse console heavily reduced too:

```
WARN: SQL Error: 17027, SQLState: null
ERROR: Le flux de données est déjà fermé
Infos: HHH000327: Error performing load command : org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not load an entity: [be.adehis.bean.Form#96]
Avertissement: EJB5184:A system exception occurred during an invocation on EJB AnswerDAO, method: public java.util.List be.adehis.database.dao.AnswerDAO.getAllAnswers() throws java.lang.Exception
Avertissement: javax.ejb.TransactionRolledbackLocalException: Exception thrown from bean
    at ...
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not load an entity: [be.adehis.bean.Form#96]
    at ... 
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not load an entity: [be.adehis.bean.Form#96]
    at ...
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Le flux de données est déjà fermé
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:113)

Avertissement: EJB5184:A system exception occurred during an invocation on EJB AnswerService, method: public java.util.List be.adehis.service.answer.AnswerService.getAllAnswers() throws java.lang.Exception
Avertissement: javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException
    at ...
Caused by: javax.ejb.TransactionRolledbackLocalException: Exception thrown from bean
    at ...
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not load an entity: [be.adehis.bean.Form#96]
    at ...
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not load an entity: [be.adehis.bean.Form#96]
    at ...
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Le flux de données est déjà fermé
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem:

[This article](http://www.razorsql.com/docs/support_oracle_long.html) say:

> When querying Oracle via JDBC, if a table that is being queried
>   contains Long or Long Raw  data, the following error message may be
>   thrown:
>
> java.sql.SQLException: Stream has already been closed

The form has an attribute questionXml containing the question formatted in xml. The answer has an attribute answerXml containing the answer formatted in xml. Both where saved in DB as `LONG`. (My fault or hibernate fault, I don't no)

I changed the type of column as `VARCHAR2(255CHAR)` and it's working now!

What is strange for me is that hibernate was able to fetch Answer > Form or Form > User but not Answer > Form > User.

**Anyway change LONG to VARCHAR2 and it's working.**

Answer (score 0):

May be you can try @NotFound( action = NotFoundAction.IGNORE )  on Many - One and see whether that resolves the issues.i have not tried but sometimes corrupted data may generate the issue.

Comment: I put `@NotFound( action = NotFoundAction.IGNORE )` on user and form attriburtes in answer class and on user and category in form class: same error :'(

Answer (score 0):

I'm no expert in Hibernate, but it looks like your DB connection gets closed before query completes:

`Le flux de données est déjà fermé => The data stream is already closed.`

¿Any other threads that could be closing it? Or maybe your server is reclaiming them at an unlucky time due to leak detection. Take a look at [this](https://blogs.oracle.com/arungupta/entry/totd_164_jdbc_statement_leak) and see if tweaking [those settings](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2416/ggndx.html#gktec) gets you in the right direction.

Comment: Yes, i agree with the fact that the connection looks to be closed but I'm in dev phase and I'm the only one to use the application. I didn't find any thread that access to the database, and no other SQL query are logged in the console. I will take a look about your links and will post back any news about this

Comment: Due to your second link, I did this: `asadmin set resources.jdbc-connection-pool.pool-name.statement-leak-timeout-in-seconds=300` and `asadmin set resources.jdbc-connection-pool.pool-name.statement-leak-reclaim=true` but it still throws the same error:
`WARN: SQL Error: 17027, SQLState: null
ERROR: Le flux de données est déjà fermé` and the same stack trace. :(